# conflict with qtip2 and jquery SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

I'm using two libraries: qTip2 and Jquery SVG. The Jquery SVG contains several js files, I have problem with jquery.svgdom.min.js. The problem in that I have conflict with this two libraries. When I disable `jquery.svgdom.min.js` the `qTip` works fine. If it enabled then I get the following error:

```
Uncaught exception: TypeError: 'this.each' is not a function  
Error thrown at line 7, column 3420 in <anonymous function: $.fn.attr>(b, c, d) in http://localhost:46159/Scripts/jquery.svgdom.min.js:
```

How to resolve it?

This is my code:

```
 function setupTolltip() {
        var sessionId = $("#schemaImage").attr("session");
        var clientId = $("#schemaImage").attr("client");
        $("area").each(function () {
            var levelId = $(this).attr("level");
            $(this).qtip(
                {
                    content: {
                        text: 'Working...',
                        ajax: {
                            url: '/hall/GetInfoForLevel',
                            data: { levelId: levelId, sessionId: sessionId, clientId: clientId },
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function (json) {
                                var content = "<div>All: " + json.PlacesCount + "<br/>Free: " + json.FreePlacesCount + "</div>";
                                this.set('content.text', content);
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    position: {
                        target: 'mouse',
                        adjust: {
                            x: 10
                        }

                    },
                    style: {
                        classes: 'ui-tooltip-tipsy ui-tooltip-shadow'
                    }

                });
        });
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
This is my all scripts:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~//Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~//Scripts/jquery.galleriffic.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.opacityrollover.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/custom-form-elements.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/datepicker.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.qtip.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>     
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**UPDATE 2:**
To `undefined` user:
I tryed like that:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

        var sessionId = $("#schemaImage").attr("session");
        var clientId = $("#schemaImage").attr("client");

        $j('area').each(function () {
....
```

but I get error:

```
Uncaught exception: TypeError: '$' is not a function
Error thrown at line 5, column 8 in setupTolltip():
    var sessionId = $("#schemaImage").attr("session");
called from line 49, column 12 in <anonymous function>():
    setupTolltip();
called via Function.prototype.apply() from line 2, column 23204 in <anonymous function: each>(a, c, d) in http://localhost:46159/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js:
    if(c.apply(a[g++],d)===!1)
called from line 2, column 16574 in <anonymous function: each>(a, b) in http://localhost:46159/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js:
    return e.each(this,a,b)
called from line 4, column 20656 in <anonymous function: complete>(a, b, c) in http://localhost:46159/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js:
    c=a.responseText,a.isResolved()&&(a.done(function(a){c=a}),i.html(g?f("<div>").append(c.replace(bM,"")).find(g):c)),d&&i.each(d,[c,b,a])
called via Function.prototype.apply() from line 2, column 29284 in <anonymous function: f.Callbacks>(b, f) in http://localhost:46159/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js:
    f=f||[],e=!a.memory||[b,f],i=!0,j=!0,m=k||0,k=0,l=c.length;
called from line 2, column 30902 in <anonymous function: fireWith>(b, c) in http://localhost:46159/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js:
    d&&(j?a.once||d.push([b,c]):(!a.once||!e)&&o(b,c));
called from line 4, column 24458 in w(a, c, l, m) in http://localhost:46159/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js:
    v.status=a,v.statusText=""+(c||w),o?h.resolveWith(e,[r,w,v]):h.rejectWith(e,[v,w,u]),v.statusCode(j),j=b,t&&g.trigger("ajax"+(o?"Success":"Error"),[v,d,o?r:u]),i.fireWith(e,[v,w]),t&&(g.trigger("ajaxComplete",[v,d]),--f.active||f.event.trigger("ajaxStop"))
called from line 4, column 36227 in <anonymous function: d>(a, e) in http://localhost:46159/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js:
    m&&g(j,k,m,l)
```

SOLUTION:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/svg-svgdom-error-this-each-is-not-a-function

Comment: do you load 2 different versions of jQuery?

Comment: No, I have one version of jQuery

Comment: try `jQuery.noConflict()`

    `var $j = jQuery.noConflict()`

then:

   `$j('selector')`

Comment: @undefined: see update 2, please.

Comment: as you have used noConflict and then `$()` should not be used `$("#schemaImage")`? => `$j("#schemaImage")`

Comment: @undefined: How can I return back? i.e, $ means jquery?

Comment: **ALWAYS trust only the most respected libraries**. You don't go buying stuff on the internet from any webstore but only those that you think are trustworthy. One of your libraries is not playing along nicely and overriding jQuery's default functionality. **Solution: replace that library** cause it's no good. It may be doing more things like that and all you'll end up with is plumbing code to avoids it's shortcomings.

Comment: @user1260827: in your case $j means jquery and not $... that's what you defined by `noConflict`